# Axis scale for a pdf plot

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of data which are distributed as a pdf function. When I plot the histogram
`histogram(mydata, nbin, "Normalization", 'pdf')` the y-axis has a scale that I don't understand. Indeed,the scale is [0 200] while I was expecting a pdf scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. I don't know if it is significant, but the documentation page for [`histogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) has `normalization` as a character vector and not a string object (single quotes not double quotes).
2. It is perfectly OK for the y-axis to be that large.  The PDF normalization makes the sum of the area of the bars equal to 1.

Comment: Single or double quotes shouldn't matter any more in newer MATLAB versions. Capitalisation though, `normalization` vs `Normalization` will be.

Comment: At least, I found the solution. The problem was that my data were too near 0, so for matlab they were distributed near the peak. Changing the unit the y-axis scale became normal.